# AS3 - physical size of the desktop screen

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, browser

I want to show a ruler in my web page that has exact size with a ruler in the real world (with cm, inches, etc). I'm tried to determine real DPI or physical size of the screen in the web browser, but this is impossible.

Is there a way to do it with AS3 or some different way in the browser?

Comment: I don't think this is something you'll be able to do with 100% accuracy across all clients.  Though I would be happy to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 2):

If available, the screen dpi will be available, using AS3, in :

```
flash.system.Capabilities.screenDPI
```

It should be available most of the time.

Comment: I'm using 2 monitors, first is 23', second is 21'. Both of them shows **screenDPI** == **72**. As I understood I can't get physical size this way

Comment: Just divide the stage size by the DPI value you get.

Comment: **screenDPI == 72** is saying difference of screen pixels against real world inch is 72. Example `someObject.width = 72;` is equal to "this someObject is one inch long" (monitor size doesn't matter, its what you do with it that counts..)

Comment: The problem is that you're not getting a real number.  72 is some standard number that all desktop monitors report.  The real number is different and changes with each device (monitor).  Desktop monitors are averaging around 95 or 96 dpi now I think - I don't research this.  My Monitor is older and is 92 dpi - Samsung LED 1920x1080.  I don't think you can get the actual number for a desktop monitor.  Create a calibration tool - user puts ruler up to monitor and can tell the app what an inch is using mouse.

Comment: Thank you for the all answers. I made a special calibration tool - so I used interaction with user for getting real-world size